# postgresql: how to convert UTC timestamp to Sydney time

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp, utc

I have a PostgreSQL DB with many tables that store timestamps in Sydney/Australia local time. In addition, I have one table which stores timestamps in UTC. This cannot be changed.

My question is - 
What SQL manipulation do I need to use in order to get the UTC timestamps in local Sydney/Australia time?

I am conscious of the fact that Sydney has periods of daylight savings, and I'm not sure how to write my SQL so that the conversion will always be correct - no matter if the timestamp was taken during daylight saving or not.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 5):

use `at time zone` like:

```
t=# select now() at time zone 'AEDT';
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------
timezone | 2016-10-11 08:20:39.067256

Time: 2.439 ms
```

there is an [outdated list of timezones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/static/timezones.html) for example
or just use `pg_timezone_names`:

```
t=# select * from pg_timezone_names()  where name ilike '%sydney%';
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------------
name       | posix/Australia/Sydney
abbrev     | AEDT
utc_offset | 11:00:00
is_dst     | t
-[ RECORD 2 ]----------------------
name       | Australia/Sydney
abbrev     | AEDT
utc_offset | 11:00:00
is_dst     | t

Time: 171.649 ms
```

Comment: So assuming I have the 2 following records:

Comment: if you have pre 9.0 release (which has `pg_timezone_names`) then use a web link above